# (Angular 8) ngx-translate is showing translation path

Tags: angular, translation, ngx-translate

I know there are lots of related questions, yet, none of them fixed my problem.

I'm using `"@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1"`, and ever since I updated from version `^8.0.0`, all my translations stopped working. (I was forced to update it because of rxjs).

Thing is, I believe nothing `should` have changed in my setup with version 8.0.0 to version 11.0.1, this is how things are built:

app.module.ts:

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
...
imports: [
    ...
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    })
]
```

And then , in my `shared.module.ts`, I import it normally:

```
imports: [
     ...
     TranslateModule,
     ...
 ]
```

Also, in my `app.component.ts`:

```
constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService,
    ...
) {
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en-US');
}
```

The translation file is called `en-US.json` and is under `assets/i18n`, normally.

Yet, all my translations look like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Here's a sample of the translation being used:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/forgotPassword']"
            class="cp-forgot-password">{{ 'labels.forgotPassword' | translate }}</a>
```

And here's a piece of my json:

```
{
  "labels": {

    ...
    "forgotPassword": "Forgot your password?",
    ...
  },
```

I have also tried chaning the i18n to `'../assets/i18n/'` or `'/assets/i18n/'`, but nothing works either way

Comment: What is the version of `@ngx-translate/http-loader`? and how are you using it to translate? can you add a sample of an HTML code using the translate directive?

Comment: hey, forgot about that. "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0"

Comment: Can you please add a sample of an HTML code using the translate directive?

Comment: @yazantahhan Added it!

Comment: Can you have a look at your network tab and look if the file is loaded?
Maybe a minimal reproduction will help you find the error, if not it will help us. Head over to https://stackblitz.com to make one.